# YouTube video in responsive iframe not showing up in Firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, responsive-design, video-embedding

I am building a responsive website that has an embedded youtube video on it. The video is in a responsive iframe and works perfectly fine in all browsers except in Firefox. There it simply doesn't show up.

I tried savemode, adding html5 to the link, commenting all js and js-queries out. If I add the width and height in px it does show and works fine, but then it's not responsive.

I can make it show up by changing the height of the container into a percentage or vw-value. No matter what figure I add, it will always render the video double height and cutting off big parts of left and right sides. Also it will cut off more of the width when the viewport shrinks. When changing the container value to anything other than 0, the same happens in all other browsers.

Tried Firebug, but that doesn't even see the iframe.

Here is the code:

```css
.embed-container { 
 position: relative; 
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
 height: 0; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 max-width: 100%; 
 margin-bottom: 4vw;
} 
 
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="embed-container">
  <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed//EyhQN24InWg?html5=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

web url:
https://www.marjanderksen.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use FitVids.js?

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".embed-container").fitVids();
  });
</script>
```

Link to download plugin: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js